# How to find slope of time series variable

Tags: python, r, regression

I have a time series data similar to this

```
            val
2015-10-15  7.85
2015-10-16  8
2015-10-19  8.18
2015-10-20  5.39
2015-10-21  2.38
2015-10-22  1.98
2015-10-23  9.25
2015-10-26  14.29
2015-10-27  15.52
2015-10-28  15.93
2015-10-29  15.79
2015-10-30  13.83
```

How can i find the slope of the adjecent rows (eg 8 and 7.85) of **val** variable and print it in a different column in R or python

I know the formula for a slope that is

[image]

but the problem is how we will take difference of **x** (that is date) values in a time series data
(Here x is date and y is val)

Answer (score 0):

If by slope you mean (value(y)-value(x))/(y-x), then your slope should have at least one value less than your data frame, so it will be difficult to show it in the same data frame.

In R, this would be my answer:

```
slope<-numeric(length = nrow(df))
for(i in 2:(nrow(df)){
  slope[i-1]<-(df[i-1,"val"]-df[i,"val"])/(as.numeric(df[i-1,1]-df[i,1]))
}
slope[nrow(df)]<-NA
df$slope<-slope
```

### Edit (answering to your edition)

In R, dates is a class of data (like integers, numeric, or characters).
For example I can define a vector of dates:

```
x<-as.Date(c("2015-10-15","2015-10-16"))
print( x )
[1] "2015-10-15" "2015-10-16"
```

And the difference of 2 dates returns:

```
x[2]-x[1]
Time difference of 1 days
```

As you mentioned, you cannot divide by a date:

```
2/(x[2]-x[1])
Error in `/.difftime`(2, (x[2] - x[1])) : 
  second argument cannot be "difftime"
```

That is why I used as.numeric, which forces the vector to be a numeric value (in days):

```
2/as.numeric(x[2]-x[1])
[1] 2
```

To prove that it works:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("2016-10-15")-as.Date("2015-10-16"))
[1] 365
```

(2016 being a bissextile year, this is correct!)